# send instance of object in web-project

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, send, instanceof

I am writing web-project in C# on asp.net.
I want to pass instance of object when navigating from one page to another.

For example I have a class

```
public partial class A: System.Web.UI.Page{
   private Item item = new Item();//I have a class Item

   protected  void btn1_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
   {
      Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx");//Here I want to send item object to the nextpage
   }
}
```

And I have a class

```
public partial class nextpage: System.Web.UI.Page{
    Item myItem;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       myItem = //item sent from page A
    }       
}
```

So, is there any way to send instance of object from one page to another, like sending variables through get query?

Please, do not recommend to use Session, this is not appropriate due to my algorithm because I have many hyperlinks:

```
for (int i = 0; i < store1.items.Count(); i++) {
    HyperLink h = new HyperLink();
    h.Text = store1.items[i].Name;
    h.NavigateUrl = "item.aspx";//here I must send items[i] when clicking at this hyperlink
    this.Form.Controls.Add(h);
    this.Form.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
}
```

So when user clicks at hyperlink he/she must be redirected to item.aspx and also send appropiate item to that page.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing that Sessions are intended for. Please explain exactly *why* sessions won't be appropriate before dismissing the most obvious answer!

Comment: I have hyperlinks, the amount is changable. I am updating my question above..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session Variable to send the Object across different web Pages in a Project.

```
public partial class A: System.Web.UI.Page{    
    private Item item = new Item();//I have a class Item  
    Session["myItem"]=myItem;   
    protected  void btn1_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
        {       Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx");
        //Here I want to send item object to the nextpage
        }
 }

public partial class nextpage: System.Web.UI.Page{
     Item myItem;
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        myItem =(Cast to It's Type) Session["myItem"];
     }
}
```

Comment: I wrote above do not recommend to use session

Comment: sorry i didn't noticed your comment...if sessions are not to be used then only way i can see is to use  "HttpContext.Current.Items" to pass the values..u need to use Server.Transfer in that and data is available to only one request...you can find more info on google...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ASP.Net Cache?

Answer (score -1):

You can set your item as a query-string parameter to `nextpage.aspx`.

```
Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx?MyItem=somevalue")

public partial class nextpage: System.Web.UI.Page{
    Item myItem;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string anIdForTheItem = Request.QueryString["MyItem"];

       myItem = myDatabase.Lookup(anIdForTheItem);

       // You can also use Request.Params["MyItem"], but be aware that Params
       // includes both GET parameters (on the query string) and POST paramaters.
    }       
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this before answering? I get compiler error on myItem = Request.QueryString["MyItem"]; Please, firstly check for correctness of syntaxis.

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov The error you are getting is because `item` is an `Item` type, and the QueryString is only useful for passing strings. I've fixed the compilation error now (although I still haven't tested it - I'm not near a compiler). You could pass some lookup on the query-string (e.g. a database ID as I've shown in my example above), or encode your item into a string for passing on the query-string if you *absolutely* cannot use sessions. If you want to pass objects around, I really would recommend using `Session` though...